# How to check availability of internet connection(Wifi, GPRS, EDGE) in Blackberry

Tags: blackberry, connection

How to check availability of internet connection(Wifi, GPRS, EDGE) in Blackberry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this....it worked for me .

```
protected static boolean isInternetAvailable() {

        boolean flag = false; 

        if(WLANInfo.getWLANState() == WLANInfo.WLAN_STATE_CONNECTED){
            flag = true;
        }
        else if(RadioInfo.isDataServiceOperational()){
            flag = true;
        }

        return flag;
    }
```